# Using getJSON to access Flickr data

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, flickr

I'm trying to access the JSON data for this user and write the id of the person using this code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

$.getJSON('https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=' + API_KEY + '&user_id=22694125@N02&format=json&jsoncallback=?', function(results){
      document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results.photos.photo[6].id);
  });</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it doesn't return anything. Help?

Comment: document.write will obliterate your entire page and code.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I dont have anything else on the page, I just want to print the photo ID

Comment: what happens when you place the URL (with your API key) into a browser?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I get this: jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":6,"perpage":100,"total":"595","photo":[{"id":"14150748552","owner":"22694125@N02","secret":"cb6aa07961","server":"7357","farm":8,"title":"union station","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"14130209031","owner":"22694125@N02","secret":"ce21e5d60c","server":"7451","farm":8,"title":"ttc & cntower","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"14104453842","owner":"22694125@N02","secret":"51d7272c69","server":"7403","farm":8,"title":"scotiabank nuit blanche","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},...

Comment: [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging). I think the request is fine, but you might not be accessing the response correctly.

Comment: As I just said. `results.photos.photo` is an **array**. It doesn't have an `id` property. The objects *inside* array have an `id` property. You either have to loop over `results.photos.photo`, or access the `i`th element. See the link above to learn how.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't return JSON. It returns javascript...

Comment: @FelixKling How do I access the id from the array? (sorry beginner at programming)

Comment: @LeeTaylor can't i still access the id?

Comment: You first have to decide which of the objects in the array you want to access. The first one? The second one? All of them? E.g. to access the ID of the first object: `results.photos.photo[0].id`. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json to learn how to access nested objects and arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements might be helpful as well.

Comment: @FelixKling even when i enter results.photos.photo[0].id, i still don't get any text on the screen

Comment: Then the issue might be that the request is not even sent, I don't know. I already posted to links to resource about how to debug JavaScript. Add some `console.log` statements to find out which part of your code successfully executes. Set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc. We cannot debug your code for you, that's something you have to do on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I've read I think you need to something like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPhotos&api_key=[APIKEY]&user_id=22694125@N02&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I believe the calls have to be JSONP (not JSON).

Comment: You are correct, but `$.getJSON` handles JSONP as well, if it detects `=?` in the URL. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp. So it's unlikely that this makes any difference.

Comment: Ah, ok. Fair enough. I don't have a valid API key to test it out.

Comment: Me neither... but I tried it without a key and jQuery correctly replaced the `jsoncallback=?` part and the response looked good as well (of course it said that I don't have a valid API key).

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in a fiddle with the same result!

Comment: The AJAX version doesn't work either, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong considering my whole code is up there ^

Comment: What does the console output with the code in my answer?

Comment: @LeeTaylor It's odd because it outputs nothing.

Comment: @user3205630: Is the request even sent at all? Check the network tab in the developer tools. Check the console for errors.

Comment: @FelixKling The request isn't sent either, but I don't know how to fix that, I'm not sure what's going wrong :(

Comment: @user3205630: Since we can't look at your computer, we can't really tell you either. Make sure jQuery is loaded, you don't have any syntax errors, etc. But that would show up on the console anyway.

Comment: @FelixKling The JQuery goes through, it says 304 Not Modified. There are no syntax errors because the console is empty.

Comment: @user3205630: All I can give you is this http://jsfiddle.net/kBxXk/, where you insert your API key and work your way from there.

Comment: @FelixKling It works on jsfiddle.net but not on my computer...weird.

Comment: @user3205630: Oh god, I just saw it. You gave the script element a `src` attribute *and* put code inside of it. That doesn't work. You have to use two `script` elements. Please see this jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: Well spotted @FelixKling!

Comment: @FelixKling omg... I did not notice that. Thank you so much!